# ionic cordova resources does not seem to work within Bitrise

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, fastlane, bitrise

I am trying to set up an Ionic build on Bitrise with a Fastlane script. As part of the build process a js script is run via node:

```
  sh "cd .. && node ./scripts/setupEnvironment.js --env=#{environment}"
```

The final step of this js script is to run `exec('ionic cordova resources --force');` in order to recreate the resources. If I run the Fastlane lane directly this all works fine, and if I run the `ionic cordova resources` command directly it works fine too. It's only when I run `bitrise run primary` on a fresh clone that it never seems to generate the resources, and fails with the error "Exit status of command 'cordova platform add android' was 1 instead of 0. (FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneShellError)
Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png"

If I run Fastlane or `ionic cordova resources` at any time, then delete the 'resources/android' directory that was created, Bitrise then has no problem running and will happily create the resources in future. It's as if the 'resources/android' folder needs to be created once (and can then be deleted) before Bitrise will be able to create the resources in future.

Comment: Seems like an issue somewhere in the repository, maybe some permission or lowercase/uppercase issue (git has a few of these). Did you try to do a clean git clone on your own Mac/PC **into a new directory** and run the fastlane script there? That can help with git commit/history related issues, at least to reproduce it locally (bitrise does the same, it does a completely new git clone into an empty directory).

Comment: @ViktorBenei thanks for your reply, if I clone the repo into a new empty directory, then copy the bitrise.yml and .bitrise.secrets.yml into the new dir, then run `bitrise run primary` I get the same error. My fastlane script contains the line `sh "cd .. && node ./scripts/setupEnvironment.js --env=#{environment}"` which kicked off the setupEnvironment.js script. Within setupEnvironment.js there is a call 'child_process.exec('ionic cordova resources --force')` which then fails to create the resources/android directory and icons. Could there be a problem with these?

Comment: is that directory (`resources/android `) committed into the repository? Also, are you sure you use the latest versions of those Bitrise steps? I think `cordova platform add android` was removed in a recent version of the Cordova related steps, it should no longer do that 

Comment: The `resources/android` directory does not exist in the repo, only `resources`. I tried to run a plain 'Script' step that only called `ionic cordova platform add android` and this still fails with "Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png".

Comment: So it seems if I ignore the error and then run `ionic cordova resources` then the resource directory is created successfully, and then I can complete the build process with no problems. I cannot call `ionic cordova resources` before first calling `ionic cordova platform add android` so it looks like for now I'll just have to go with ignoring the error from 'platform add' and then run 'resources'

Comment: Glad to hear you managed to find a workaround - though it might worth to dig into a bit when you have some time why this is required, AFAIK you shouldn't have to run `ionic cordova platform add ...` in a CI environment, only once on your Mac/PC when you init that specific platform.